How to navigate web with scraping navigation?
I want to go this page: https://divar.ir/s/tehran.
select one item and click contact address and finally getting contact data with web scraping?
code :
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://divar.ir/s/tehran'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('div', id='post-list-container-id')
for title in titles:
    ele = title.find('a')
hrf = 'https://divar.ir'+ (ele['href'])

res = requests.get(hrf)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
ttles = soup.find_all('div')
for title in titles:
    ele = title.find('div')
print(ele)

can anyone help me?
